# Can Jedi use legacy force lightning?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Ok so I do it whenever I see the little legacy force lightning symbol as that is my favorite move to use. I don't know how I activate or if it is random or what. Can a Jedi knight or consular use the legacy force lightning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  The Legacy abilities are just that — usable by every character in your Legacy.  There are no faction, class, or alignment restrictions on them; even a non-Force-sensitive class can use Legacy Force Lightning.

Your unlocked Legacy abilities are only usable after activating (and during) your Heroic Moment ability.  They are unlocked by completing the Chapter 3 storylines for each class.  You can view those unlocks by pressing Y to open the Legacy Panel and going to the "Imperial Classes" and "Republic Classes" parts of the "Global Unlocks" section at the top left.

Comment: See also this official link: http://www.swtor.com/info/legacy (Scroll down to "Class Unlocks")